# Get a specific line results

Tags: powershell

Let's say I have big text file with results like this for each file I checked:

```
    ...
    Results for: C:\test\test.dll
    Dynamic Base    : "Present"
    ASLR            : "Present"
    High Entropy VA : "Present"
    Force Integrity : "NotPresent"
    Isolation       : "Present"
    NX              : "Present"
    SEH             : "NotPresent"
    CFG             : "NotPresent"
    RFG             : "NotPresent"
    SafeSEH         : "NotPresent"
    GS              : "NotPresent"
    Authenticode    : "NotPresent"
    .NET            : "Present"

    Results for: C:\test\test2.dll
    Dynamic Base    : "Present"
    ASLR            : "Present"
    High Entropy VA : "Present"
    Force Integrity : "NotPresent"
    Isolation       : "Present"
    NX              : "Present"
    SEH             : "NotPresent"
    CFG             : "NotPresent"
    RFG             : "NotPresent"
    SafeSEH         : "NotPresent"
    GS              : "NotPresent"
    Authenticode    : "NotPresent"
    .NET            : "Present"
    ...
```

My script checks each line and search a specific file name, in this case lets say **test2.dll**

```
Foreach($line in Get-Content results.txt) {
   if($line -like '*test2.dll*') {
                    
   }
}
```

How to get results 6 rows below **Results for: C:\test\test2.dll**, for example from **NX** line

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.IndexOf` to get the element index for the specific line, then decrease the number by 6:

```
$results = Get-Content results.txt
Foreach($line in $results) {
   if($line -like '*test2.dll*') {
          ## Get the data of 6 rows before
          $results[$results.IndexOf($line)-6]   
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a (slightly convoluted) way to convert your file to some objects:

```
Select-String -Path <path-to-data-file> -Pattern 'Results for: (.*)' -Context 0,13 |
    ForEach-Object {$files = @()}{
        $file = [PsCustomObject]@{
            Name = $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value
        }

        $_.Context.PostContext |
            ForEach-Object {
                $propertyParts = $_.Split(':').Trim() -replace '"', ''

                $file | Add-Member -MemberType 'NoteProperty' -Name $propertyParts[0] -Value $propertyParts[1]
            }

        $files += $file
    }
```

You can then manipulate the collection using standard PowerShell techniques.  For example, you can get the 'NX' value for 'test2.dll' by doing this:

```
($files | Where-Object Name -like '*test2.dll').NX
```